# WiFi slows down when using bluetooth headset

Tags: wireless, 18.04, bluetooth

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS new to Linux.

Like title says WiFi slows down when using Bluetooth headset.

It's cheap Asus laptop and everything works right out of box on Ubuntu.
My specs are as following

```
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
                          system         E402NA
/0                        bus            E402NA
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/e                      memory         2GiB System Memory
/0/e/0                    memory         2GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.
/0/11                     memory         112KiB L1 cache
/0/12                     memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/13                     processor      Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
/0/100                    bridge         Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/0.1                generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/2                  display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/e                  multimedia     Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/f                  communication  Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/12                 storage        Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/13                 bridge         Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/13/0               generic        RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/13/0.2  enp1s0f2   network        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet cont
/0/100/13.1               bridge         Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/13.1/0  wlp2s0     network        QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapt
/0/100/15                 bus            Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/15/0    usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/15/0/4             communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/15/0/5             multimedia     USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
/0/100/15/1    usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                 generic        Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/17                 generic        Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/1c                 generic        Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/1f                 bridge         Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 
/0/100/1f.1               bus            Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900
```

edit:
additional info requested by @vidario

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TP-Link_D236"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: AC:84:C6:B3:D2:36   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-12 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:41   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0f2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

also additional info requested from @heynnema

```
##  sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
       logical name: enp1s0f2
       version: 06
       serial: b0:6e:bf:0c:ba:67
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:22 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:91214000-91214fff memory:91210000-91213fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:9f:38:5c:ce:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.18.0-18-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.195 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:23 memory:91100000-9117ffff memory:91180000-9118ffff
 ##
```

```
grep -i bt /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:options bt87x index=-2
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf:options ath9k btcoex_enable=1
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf:blacklist btaudio
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `iwconfig` when connected to WiFi? If it's 2.4GHz net, there may be severe interference.

Comment: Related info about Wifi channels and the fact that BT uses the very same frequencies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels - Selecting a different channel for WiFi may be one way to avoid trouble.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `grep -i bt /etc/modprobe.d/*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema ty for reply, updated original post with requested additional  info.

Comment: It looks like the wireless driver ath9k already has the `options ath9k btcoex_enable=1` option enabled. So it's as bluetooth friendly as it can be. Try setting your wireless network to a different channel in your router. Try channel 1 or 6 or 11.

Comment: Different channel is the first thing i tried without luck, upon learning frequency clash.